# How to set uid and gid in Docker Compose?

Tags: bash, shell, docker, docker-compose

I can execute a `docker run` command as such ...

```
docker run --rm  --user $(id -u):$(id -g) -e MYDATA=/some/path/to/data -e USER=$USER -p 8883-8887:8883-8887 ...
```

However, in Docker Compose, when I write out the following ...

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  container_name: some-server
  image: some:img
  user: $(id -u):$(id -g) 
  ...
```

... it does not work.

I understand I am asking `docker-compose up` to perform sub shell command substitution, and it cannot.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: More to the point, Docker Compose is not shell, so it doesn't do [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html).

Comment: **Update:** The ability to automatically process `UID` and `GID` vars will **not** be added to compose. Reasoning is solidly explained [here](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/issues/94) as a potential security hole in a declarative language. Previously, this was an [open but now closed issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2380).

Comment: Note that the edit to this question which added an application-specific fail case doubling the question length was rolled back. Edits should "clarify the meaning of the post," according to the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). Adding a real-life example is very helpful, but one that is longer than a few lines detracts from the original focus. A hyperlink or a shorter edit would be better, I think. Alternately, an answer that shows a specific example and how to solve it would certainly earn votes.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Try [this](https://dev.to/acro5piano/specifying-user-and-group-in-docker-i2e)

So, you need to put:

```
user: "${UID}:${GID}"
```

in your docker compose and provide UID and GID as docker-compose parameter

```
UID=${UID} GID=${GID} docker-compose up
```

(or define UID and GID as environment variables).

Comment: Thanks. Apparently that is the only good answer at this point. You get the answer credit.

Comment: Why do you need to explicitly set UID and GID to the same value they already have? Why doesn't just "docker-compose up" suffice? Edit: found the answer; they are shell variables and not environment variables. https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4725

Comment: Perhaps more efficiently: `UID="$(id -u)" GID="$(id -g)" docker-compose up` Alternately, `UID_GID="$(id -u):$(id -g)" docker-compose up` (and within compose set `user: "${UID_GID}"` ...

Comment: for me, it worked when I used my docker-compose file without quotes like this: `user: ${UID_GID}`. I'm using docker-compose `version: '3.8'`

Comment: `$ UID=xxx cmd` is not a good idea for all the shells, as (e.g.) in bash UID is a read-only variable and already exists, but not exported. Comment by @ingyhere is really the way to go.

Comment: @ingyhere that "${UID_GID}" is also sometimes called "${UGID}".

Comment: @questionto42: Thanks, where is this used? I could not find a lot of matches in Google.

Comment: @ingyhere I have seen it at [Getting started with ROS and Docker Compose](https://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/Compose). It is just good to name it here in case someone searches for the keyword.

Comment: I suggest you use `env_file: .env`  and have each user create the .env file with the content UID=1000 (or that user's ID)

Comment: I get error "services.web.user must be a string" when I set `user:` with a user id instead of username.

Comment: Does it work on Windows?

Comment: I update example

Comment: In case you want to fail early you can also put question marks next to your variables like this: `user: "${UID:?}:${GID:?}"`.
I prefer to do this generally so I don't end up debugging the weirdness that happens if I forget one or several of them.

Answer (score 17):

This can be done as well

**In your docker-composer.yml**

```
user: $DOCKER_USER
```

**In the command line**

```
echo 'export DOCKER_USER="$(id -u):$(id -g)"' >> ~/.bash_profile

source ~/.bash_profile

docker-compose up
```

Created a DOCKER_USER variable and added it in the bash_profile for persistency.  The source will  help the shell to recognize changes of .bash_profile on demand

Comment: 'user' goes under the services: -> name

Answer (score 3):

add following command line arguments on docker build image:

```
docker build --build-arg UID="$(id -u)" --build-arg GID="$(id -g)" --build-arg UNAME="$(whoami)" . -t tagname -f docker.recipe
```

append following lines at the begin of the docker recipe:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS yoursystem

ARG UID
ARG GID
ARG UNAME
RUN groupadd -g ${GID} -o ${UNAME}
RUN useradd -m -u ${UID} -g ${GID} -o -s /bin/bash ${UNAME}
```

Comment: I prefer `RUN usermod -u ${UID} www-data; groupmod -g ${GID} www-data` assuming www-data is your you're trying to mod.