# How to pass dynamic build args via Compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-build

I am currently building a container in my compose with a command

`docker compose build --build-arg VAR_NAME=$(some_command) service_name`

and I would like to build the same container with the simpler command `docker compose build service_name`, but I have not found a way to have docker compute the new output of `some_command` at each build.

To accomplish this I can freely change both the compose file and the Dockerfile for the container.

Is there any way to have docker instantiate a build argument or some other kind of variables dynamically on each build?

What I tried so far:

My first idea was to do something like the following

```
services:
    service_name:
        build:
            context: ./service_name
            args:
                VAR_NAME: $(some_command)
```

or

```
                VAR_NAME: "$(some_command)"
```

or

```
                VAR_NAME: "$$(some_command)"
```

but none of them works, even if

```
services:
    service_name:
        build:
            context: ./service_name
            args:
                VAR_NAME: 'example of some_command output'
```

works correctly.

Comment: i don't think you can set build args dynamically in a docker-compose file. i use build scripts for this. for example `build.sh` contains `docker-compose build  --build-arg MY_VAR=$(command)`

Comment: [How to set uid and gid in Docker Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56844746/how-to-set-uid-and-gid-in-docker-compose) discusses a similar problem (trying to set `user: $(id -u)`) and notes that you cannot do command substitution or other advanced shell substitutions in a Compose file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that docker does not support running shell commands in a `docker-compose.yml`

see the [Using shell command in docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4081) github discussion

you could use a script to wrap your build command.

```bash
# build.sh

docker-compose build --build-arg MY_VAR=$(command)
```

Comment: In the future I might have containers that use similar build args with different per-container values. I guess I will have to rename them.

Comment: It looks heavy but it does work, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@tom's answer is likely better but out of stubbornness I decided to generate a [`docker-compose.ovverride.yml`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#understanding-multiple-compose-files) with the correct values.

I went for ad-hoc template processed with `sed`:

`docker-compose.template`:

```
services:
    admin:
        build:
            args:
                VAR_NAME: __VAR_NAME__
                VAR_NAME2: __VAR_NAME2__
```

and a simple sed script:

```
sed \
  -e "s/__VAR_NAME__/$(some_command)/g" \
  -e "s/__VAR_NAME2__/$(some_command2)/g" \
  ./docker-compose.template \
  > ./docker-compose.override.yml
```

This is quite ugly but works for my use-case

TODO:

1. Fix escaping in `sed`'s regex pattern, currently the output is in the pattern `[0-9]+` so it is fine
2. Use a better template language