# Share files between docker host and container in a volume, best practice (UID)

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, containers, userid

I'm trying to set up a Docker host, but I want to make it right from the start, and there is one concept I don't understand:

If I write a file from within the container to a mounted volume, it has the UID of the user from the container, even if the same UID doesn't exist on the host.

I know that I can set the container to run as a different user, but this might break things if the container image expects it to be run as a specific user.

If I have a bunch of containers running later, my goal is that every file in a volume is owned by a single host user, so that adding/changing files doesn't cause permission conflicts for the container.
(Example: I add a file as a different user from the host so the container can't modify it.)

What's the best practice here? How do I make it so that I have the best experience later? Here's a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

Comment: This question will probably get closed as "Opinion-based". My opinion: best practice is to avoid the use of bind mounts as anything other than sources of read-only data (and use named docker volumes to provide r/w storage to your containers).

Comment: [This answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74288291/10008173) has one approach: do not specify a user ID in the Dockerfile, make most files owned by root, do not mount code or libraries over the image content, limit writable data to a single directory (at most, ideally none) and specify the matching host uid when you run the container.