# Need to be superuser to edit a file of a django app. The django project has a Docker Container

Tags: django, linux, docker, docker-compose

I have cloned, followed the instructions, and setup the [Docker, Django, Postgres project from Docker's Github](https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose/tree/master/official-documentation-samples/django) on my Linux machine. I used `docker compose run web django-admin startapp auth` to create a directory and files for an app called `auth`. When I edit a file in `auth/`, e.g. `auth/models.py`, I get an error emssage saying I haveinsufficient permissions: [image: Insufficient permissions error message]

`auth/` is owned by root, which is confusing because `manage.py` (I believe this is the file that created `auth/`) is owned by me. To make myself the owner of `manage.py`, I ran `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER composeexample manage.py` as instructed by the ReadMe.

I've tried changing the ownership of `auth`, but this didn't make a difference - after running `sudo chown meeee:docker auth/`, I still get the same error message when I edit a file inside `auth/`

My user is a member of the docker group.
`getent group docker` returns `docker:x:998:meeee`

Edit:
I should have been using the `-R` recursive command with `chown` to change ownership of the files inside `auth/`. However, I do not want to have to `chown` every new directory created.

Comment: `I've tried changing the ownership of auth` Did you try doing it recursively (the `-R` option)? If you do not, then chown will only change the owner of the directory, not the files within the directory.

Comment: `auth/ is owned by root, which is confusing because manage.py is owned by me` The way that permissions work in Linux is that the owner of the process which created the file is the owner of the file. The owner of the process doesn't have to be the same as the owner of manage.py.

Comment: I’ve just tried `chown -R` and I can now edit the files. I don’t want to have to `chown` every new directory. Will update my question.

Comment: Then either 1) don't use docker to run manage.py or 2) [change the UID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56844746/how-to-set-uid-and-gid-in-docker-compose) of the web container to match your UID.

Comment: It's probably worthy of a new question, but I don't know how to use `manage.py` without using `docker compose run`, or entering the container's shell `docker exec -t -i {container id} bash`. Don't suppose you know? `python3 manage.py startapp auth` returns `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named django. Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?`

Comment: I have asked [How to run django manage.py commands when using docker compose to avoid issues with permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74512648/how-to-run-django-manage-py-commands-when-using-docker-compose-to-avoid-issues-w)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem with development setups that use Docker (and Docker Compose) when your container runs as `root`. You likely mount a volume with your Docker setup thus writing from inside your container to your local file system, e.g.

```
docker run --rm -it -v .:/app ubuntu:rolling
```

or, as a Docker Compose setup (`docker-compose.yml`),

```yaml
services:
  app:
    image: ubuntu:rolling
    volumes:
    - .:/app
```

The problem is that your container runs as `root`, hence the files that are created on the volume inside your container are owned by `root` (inside *and outside* your container, because of the volume).

### Use an unprivileged user

You fix this by running the container with an unprivileged user, e.g.

```
docker run --rm -it -u ${UID} -v .:/app ubuntu:rolling python manage.py
```

or

```
docker compose run -u ${UID} app python manage.py
```

### Set `USER` in your `Dockerfile`

Note that the [Docker best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#user) recommend that your set up your Docker image to run as an unprivileged user by setting `USER` in your `Dockerfile`, e.g.

```
FROM ubuntu:rolling
RUN apt update && apt install -y python3-pip
WORKDIR /app
USER ubuntu
RUN pip install django
COMMAND python manage.py runserver
```

A setup like this allows you to install system dependencies as `root` and user-space software as an unprivileged user, which the container will also use when you run the container, later.

While this is optional to solve your problem (if you always run Docker with the `-u` option) it is highly recommended, because it makes your setup safer.