# How to run django manage.py commands when using docker compose to avoid issues with permissions

Tags: django, linux, docker, docker-compose

I have created a Django, Docker, Postgres project, based on [the example on Docker's Github](https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose/tree/master/official-documentation-samples/django). On my Linux machine I have 2 Docker containers, one for Django and one for Postgres.

When I run `manage.py` commands using docker compose, such as `docker compose run web django-admin startapp auth`, the directory and files created are owned by `root`. This means I need to change the ownership each time I do this. I use `sudo chown -R`. If I don't change ownership, when I try to edit a file generated by `manage.py`, I get an error message saying I have insufficient privileges and that I need to retry as superuser.

When I try to run this command without docker compose, e.g. `python3 manage.py startapp auth`, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named django. Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?`

Is it possible for the output of the `manage.py` commands to be owned by me? I know that the docker `process` is owned by root...

Comment: Can you try this, to change Django's user inside the container so it matches your user? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56844746/how-to-set-uid-and-gid-in-docker-compose

Comment: When I tried the accepted accept solution on that article returned an error saying `UID: readonly variable. The UID variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string`

Comment: I've got it working. I'm importing UID and GID from a `.env` file. Am I right in understanding this issue is unique to Linux because Docker runs processes as `root`? Are there any articles that you could recommend to help understand this? If a Mac or Windows user joined my project, they wouldn't need to address this issue would they?

Comment: It's going to be a problem on mac, at least. It has the same issue that the UID/GID must match inside and outside the container in order for the user running Django to own the resulting files. Windows doesn't have numeric IDs, and I've never used Docker on it, so I couldn't tell you if it would work.

Comment: `UID: readonly variable.` Oh, you're on bash, right? UID is a reserved variable there. Can you try changing UID -> USER_ID, then running `USER_ID=$(id -u) GROUP_ID=$(id -g) docker-compose up` ?

Comment: Your right, I am on bash. I can start the containers using `USER_ID...` but when I run `docker compose run web django-admin startapp auth` and edit file, I get the initial error message, saying I need to be superuser.