# How to solve mismatching file owner UID between host and container in a development team?

Tags: docker, openlitespeed

#### My setup

- Windows 11
- WSL2
- Docker Desktop v4.14.0 using WSL based engine

#### Known facts

- With file permission, [the numeric user id counts](https://medium.com/@mccode/understanding-how-uid-and-gid-work-in-docker-containers-c37a01d01cf)
- [OpenLitespeed Docker image](https://github.com/litespeedtech/ols-dockerfiles/blob/master/template/Dockerfile) uses `UID 999`

#### Use case

We have a project where we use Openlitespeed Docker image. The `docker-compose.yml` defines the service like this:

```
  litespeed:
    image: litespeedtech/openlitespeed:${OLS_VERSION}-${PHP_VERSION}
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    logging:
      driver: none
    volumes:
      - ./lsws/conf:/usr/local/lsws/conf
      - ./lsws/admin-conf:/usr/local/lsws/admin/conf
      - ./bin/container:/usr/local/bin
      - ./sites:/var/www/vhosts/
      - ./acme:/root/.acme.sh/
      - ./logs:/usr/local/lsws/logs/
      - ./pub:/var/www/pub/
      - ./install:/var/www/install/
      - ./config:/var/www/config/
      - ./.env:/var/www/.env
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 443:443/udp
      - 7080:7080
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      TZ: ${TimeZone}
    networks:
      - default
```

When cloning the repo to a computer, the files in the working dir are owned by the current user, say, with `UID 1000`.

When starting the container, the bind mounted directories & files inherit the owner `UID 1000` from the host computer.

The process in the container runs as `user 999` and faces permission problems because `999 != 1000`.

**Probably the files should be owned by same uid the container is running as?**

Well, we could `chown` the files to the user `999` to make it work in the container, but whenever we want to edit the bind mounted files on the host computer, we face permission errors, because files are owned by user `999`, which probably doesn't even exist on the host computer.

**Is the solution then to create the missing user with ID `999` on the host computer?**

We could create it and add the actual user to the new user's group and allow write-permissions to group (`chmod g+w`). Now the files could be edited on the host computer by the actual user, and container works too.

But then a new file is needed. One creates it on the host computer and boom - it's owned by the current user, and again the container has problems.

**How about leveraging the [SGID bit](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/suid-sgid-sticky-bit) to ensure file group stays consistent?**

This could do. If all new files and directories in that directory inherit at least the group, the permissions should work both ways as the directories and files were previously made group-writable.

Ok, could work.

**But how do we make this work across the development team?**

We can't just assume everybody can create a matching user account with `ID 999` on the host computer because that UID might very well be already reserved.

There must be a proper way to solve this, I've probably just overseen it totally.

Comment: The typical approach is to override the `user:` in the Compose file, for example [Docker-compose set user and group on mounted volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462189/docker-compose-set-user-and-group-on-mounted-volume) or [How to set uid and gid in Docker Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56844746/how-to-set-uid-and-gid-in-docker-compose).

Comment: I tried it on a Linux server, clone the repo to the host server and make sure it's owned by the current host' user and group. Then start it, in the container, the default document root folder should be owned by 1000:lsadm. Once you visit the site and trigger the process, the process well runs with User 1000 due to the External App Set UID Mode = DocRoot UID setting.  Whether I add files from the host or container, no permission issue.

Comment: @DavidMaze that would run the container as the given user, say `1000:1000`, right? The issue is that the Litespeed docker image already `chown` server config files etc to `999:1000` so overriding the container user to something else would also result in permission issues.

Comment: @Eric Thanks! Wasn't aware of the `External App Set UID Mode`. That seems to be a potential solution.

Comment: Just a confirmation that the External App Set UID Mode was a working solution \o/