# dunglas/symfony-docker permissions

Tags: docker, symfony

What is the procedure - I download the

```
dunglas/symfony-docker
```

repository,
then run the following command:

```
SYMFONY_VERSION=6.2.* docker compose up --build
```

After entering the container, I run the composer install command.

At this point, the files outside the container have root ownership.

Is there a trick to perform container operations while being able to edit them
outside the container, for example, in PHPStorm?

When i add

```
services:
  php:
    user: 1000:1000
```

clone project to new location

```
2. Run `docker compose build --pull --no-cache` to build fresh images
3. Run `docker compose up` (the logs will be displayed in the current shell)
```

get errors:

```
 In Kernel.php line 575:
 Unable to create the "cache" directory (/srv/app/var/cache/dev)
```

from host in project dir i run

```
sudo chmod 777 var
```

then

```
docker compose up
```

and same situation

```
Unable to create the "cache" directory (/srv/app/var/cache/dev).
```

soultion from https://github.com/dunglas/symfony-docker/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#editing-permissions-on-linux also not working: :

```
   docker-compose run --rm php chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) .
```

its ok but when i run composer-require - owner is not my, so i cannot edit my vendors

when i run composer update i get

```
In GitDownloader.php line 248:
                                                                                 
  Failed to execute git show-ref --head -d                                       
                                                                                 
  fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '/srv/app/vendor/..
```

Answer (score 1):

The docker container is ran as `root`, therefore, the files it creates also belong to `root`.

You can fix this by manually setting `user: <uid>:<gid>` in your `docker-compose.yml`.
This works most of the time, but not always, it depends on the image you're using.

Check out [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56844746/how-to-set-uid-and-gid-in-docker-compose) for more information.

Comment: I update example

Answer (score 0):

In that github repo there is a troubleshooting docs. You can use a command provided there:

https://github.com/dunglas/symfony-docker/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#editing-permissions-on-linux

Comment: I update example