# Can't execute powershell command in docker compose to get mac address and pass it as environment variable to container

Tags: docker, powershell, docker-compose

I am trying to execute PowerShell command inside docker-compose to get mac address of host and pass it to environment variable to be executed inside the docker container but I am getting this error:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "environment" option in service "hyper-user-mgmt": "Host_Mac=$(wmic nicconfig where "IPEnabled = True" get macaddress | findstr "0B")"
```

docker compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  hyper-user-mgmt: 
    image: Usr-Mgmt
    container_name: User-mgmt
    ports:
      - 8083:8001
    environment:
      - Host_Mac=$(wmic nicconfig where "IPEnabled = True" get macaddress | findstr "0B")
```

Comment: Compose can't execute host commands like this (it doesn't support command substitution).  [How to set uid and gid in Docker Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56844746/how-to-set-uid-and-gid-in-docker-compose) describes a similar case for the numeric user IDs.