# setup tables in PostgreSql database with docker compose only

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose with official image postgresql and i want to create a database with a table in it when i run docker compose up. I followed the instruction on docker hub but it doesn't work the container run and create my database but not my tables. I don't want to use a dockerfile.

```
version: "3"
services:

  PostgresDb:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:alpine3.18
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: matcha
      POSTGRES_USER: user123
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: abc123
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    restart: unless-stopped
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

volumes:
  postgres_data:

networks:
  net-db:
    driver: bridge`
```

init.sql file:

```
\c matcha;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    email VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    username VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
```

the logs of docker are:

```
postgres   | server started
postgres   | CREATE DATABASE
postgres   | 
postgres   | 
postgres   | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
postgres   | psql: error: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql: Permission denied
postgres   |
```

permsision denied but i chmod 777 my init.sql and i can execute it manually inside the container.

Comment: Can you show the output of `ls -lah ./docker` from your host OS to verify the permissions have indeed been set correctly?

Comment: Permissions are indeed set correctly:
drwxrwxrwx  2 usr926 2022_paris 4.0K Feb 21 13:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 usr926 2022_paris 4.0K Feb 20 19:51 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 usr926 2022_paris  217 Feb 21 14:46 init.sql

Comment: Do the `uid` & `gid` components of the output from `docker exec postgres id` match those of `id` in your host machine's shell? Seems like the user ID that the container is running as doesn't match that of `usr926:2022_paris` in the host machine - you may have to define `UID` and `GID` in the container to match the host account/group that owns this file.

Comment: uid and gid are like that in docker : uid=0(root) gid=0(root) it doesn't match but permissions of the file allow every users to read and execute it. And it is not possible to define uid and gid in the docker compose file

Comment: "*And it is not possible to define uid and gid in the docker compose file*" [Are you sure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56844746/how-to-set-uid-and-gid-in-docker-compose)

Comment: no sorry i try this but it didn't change anything

Comment: You say it works when you run it manually. Can you show the commands you use to connect to your docker container and run the sql file through psql *as user postgres not root* successfully.